# How to run multi actions in Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, debugging, scheduled-tasks

So I created task schedule (from windows Task Schedule application). So it has 3 actions. All of them starts one program but with different arguments. So the first action starts the program - I checked that with `Debugger.Launch();` method. But the second one doesn't start the program so the `Debugger.Launch();` never called.

So I think the second and third actions are never started, but I want run all them. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: You can try with different Tasks for every Action.

Comment: @DDDSoft You mean Task Scheduler or Debugger.Launch();

Comment: @DoniyorNiyozov Thanks. But it should be on one task.

Comment: @QutfulloOchilov if you can provide both, there is more chance we can reconstruct the problem.